# Why i don't get the data from the api in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to get the componentValue from my api but it is not working. I don't get any errors in terminal or in console.

This is the json that my api is giving:

```
 [
    {
    id: 100,
    componentName: "bp",
    componentValue: "120/80",
    measuredDateTime: null
    },
    {
    id: 102,
    componentName: "bp",
    componentValue: "120/80",
    measuredDateTime: null
    },
    {
    id: 107,
    componentName: "bp",
    componentValue: "50/60",
    measuredDateTime: null
    },
    {
    id: 30,
    componentName: "bp",
    componentValue: "90/149",
    measuredDateTime: "2018-03-19T18:34:24.000+00:00"
    }
    ]
```

This is my code in react:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class ChartGenerator extends React.Component{

    state={
        clinicalData:[]
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/clinicalservices/api/clinicals/1/bp").then(res=>{

            this.setState(res.data);
        })

    }


    render(){
        return (<div>
            <h2>Clinical Report:</h2>
            {this.state.clinicalData.map((item,index)=>(
                <p key={index}>{item.componentValue}</p>
            ))}

        </div>);
    }
}



export default ChartGenerator;
```

I tryed everything but it is not working!
If u know something pls help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to set the `state` is wrong. You should set your `state` like this.

```
this.setState({ clinicalData: res.data });
```

Answer (score 0):

state is an `object` so when you are setting it, you should also be setting it to an `object`.
`res.data` is an array.

```
this.setState({clinicalData: res.data})
```

this should do it